# Reference all table boxes to their individual rows and column as formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example I have a huge table of rows and columns.
I need to write a formula for the table such that the values of each box belongs to their particular row and column value.

```
 A | B | C |D  | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M |N ...  
 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |10 | 11| 12|13...  
 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 ...  
 2 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 16| 32| 64|...  
 3 | 3 |  
 4 |  
 5 |   
.  
.  
.
```

For example, B3 has the formula 'A3^B1' giving it a value of 3, C3 has the formula 'A3^C1'. But how do i copy the formula into the rest of the boxes? For now I have to **manually** key in the formulas for the boxes but that is too inefficient.
Is there a way for to compute the value just by referencing all the boxes formula to their individual column value and row value?

Comment: You won't have to extend that very far to hit a stack overflow (i.e a **#NUM!** error)!

Comment: Is there a way for me to avoid that error?

Comment: No! 64-bit Excel may delay it but it will still happen.

Comment: Could it be some thing to do with the format of the cells? I have like a 200x200 table of values to compute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in B2 and then copy it to the other cells: `=$A1^B$1`.

The `$` before a column and/or row will fix the column/row when copying the formula to other cells!

Pro tip: when editing/entering the formula, press <kbd>F4</kbd> to toggle between the multiple $ states!

And as an alternative - you can even remove the first row and column, and simply place this formula in A1: `=ROW()^COLUMN()` and you'll get the same result matrix!

Comment: Well it works. But I got a `#NUM!` error. Could it be that the result is too large for excel to handle? Or something else?